# Mapping class to a table without a table name

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have many tables in my DB with exactly the same structure: same columns names and types.
The only difference between these tables is the their names (which I can only know in runtime).

I would like to create a mapping of a class to a table but giving the name of the table only during runtime (no static `@Table` annotation).

Is it possible? 
Is there any other way to achieve my goal?

Comment: By runtime do you mean during the application startup or in response to a user action. If it is at server startup you might be able to achieve it by implementing a NamingStrategy

Answer (score 1):

Directly - no. Because this is not a regular use-case. Normally you should not have dynamcally-generated tables. It is a valid use when you move some records to an archive table (or tables), but otherwise avoid it.

Anyway, you can make that work: make a native query, and map the result to your non-entity object. You will be able to select from any table and transform the result to an object. However, you can't insert or update that way.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think associating or changing the table mapped to an entity dynamically is possible.

You can check @MappedSuperClass, which will allow you to define all fields in a class once and inherit them, so that there is no repetition and entities are empty class with mappings.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1168

If you know the table name dynamically you can always instantiate the mapped class accordingly.